# Gnuplot error weighted mean

Tags: gnuplot, mean, weighted

I have a set of data with y error bars. I can find the mean of the data without error bars using the following:

```
f(x)=mean_y
fit f(x) "data" via mean_y
```

However, I want do find a weighted mean, taking into account the error bars. Is something like this possible in gnuplot or do I have to code it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `using` parameter to specify a column for the errors. With three `using` specifiers, the third one is interpreted as standard deviation `s` and is used to compute a weight `1/s**2` for the corresponding value:

```
f(x) = mean_y
fit f(x) "data" using 1:2:3 via mean_y
```

That assumes, that your `data` file has three columns, `x`, `z` and `stdev`. If you only have two columns, `z` and `stdev`, you must use

```
fit f(x) "data" using 0:1:2 via mean_y
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I initially tried this but it gave me some weird error so I removed the zero values and it worked.